# Как ускорить время работы программы?

Tags: python

Не укладываюсь во время.
Условие задачи такое:
Маленькая лягушка хочет добраться до другой стороны реки. Сначала лягушка расположена на одном берегу реки (позиция 0) и хочет попасть на противоположный берег (позиция X + 1). Листья падают с дерева на поверхность реки.

Вам задан массив A, состоящий из N целых чисел, представляющих падающие листья. A [K] представляет положение, в котором один лист падает в момент времени K, измеряемый в секундах.

Цель состоит в том, чтобы найти самое раннее время, когда лягушка может прыгнуть на другую сторону реки. Лягушка может пересекаться только тогда, когда листья появляются в каждом положении через реку от 1 до X (то есть мы хотим найти самый ранний момент, когда все позиции от 1 до X покрыты листьями). Вы можете предположить, что скорость течения в реке ничтожно мала, т. Е. Листья не меняют свои позиции, когда они падают в реку.

```
import random
def solution(X,A):
    B=[i for i in range (1,X+1)]
    for i in range (len(A)-1):
        if A[i] in B:
            B.remove(A[i])
            if not B:
                return i
    if B:
        return -1
A=[1,3,1,4,2,3,5,4]
solution(5,A)
N=random.randint(1,100000)
X=random.randint(1,100000)
A=[]
for i in range(N):
    A.append(random.randint(1,X))
solution(X,A)
```

Comment: for i in range (len(A)-1) ->  for i in A. И далее виесто А[i] использовать i. На скорость вряд ли значительно повлияет, но это правильный способ идти по списку в питоне.

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужен как раз индекс вернуть, а не значение. Как  мне его получить если  буду идти по значениям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так (программа просто подсчитывает, сколько листомест занято):

```
def solution(X,A):
    C=[0]*(X+1)
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        pos = A[i]
        if (C[pos] == 0):
            C[pos] = 1
            cnt += 1
            if (cnt == X):
                return i
    return -1
```

Comment: А вот так всё работает, по времени прохожу. Теперь буду разбираться, что именно вы сделали)

Comment: Считаю занятые места (несколько листьев могут на одно место попасть)

Comment: А у меня была мысль удалять из массива совпадения, но это кажется в 2-3 раза дольше

Comment: Удаление ведёт к перераспределению памяти - а это обычно занимает немало времени.